# is there any complete minecraft forge documentation anywhere?

Tags: minecraft-forge

While it doesn't appear that this is a duplicate based on my searches, I'm sure other people have complained about this in many places.

I play minecraft and know java pretty well, so I thought it would be interesting to make mods with the minecraft forge. However, most tutorials are outdated or incomplete and I can't find a complete documentation. Now, if someone says, for instance, that existing blocks can be accessed through the `Blocks` class, I don't know what package that class is in. My more specific question was about modifying the properties of TNT(I wanted to do this as a test mod). Based on what I've been able to scrounge from various forums, using reflection on existing blocks in the game is possible, and what I found surrounding food would suggest there is a class for TNT somewhere that can be modified to boost its power. Just so someone can explain the not-well-explained principles of forge mod making, where would I find this TNT-related class that I could use reflection on, and how would I go about doing that(I've never done stuff with reflection before)?

To be clear, I've gotten forge minecraft all set up, I don't need an explanation of that. Just how to modify the properties of TNT(and hopefully this explanation will help me understand some broader principles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using https://nekoyue.github.io/ForgeJavaDocs-NG/ for a while. It has 1.12.2, 1.13.2, 1.14.4, 1.15.2, 1.16.5 and 1.17.1

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot more complete than what I had found

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a complete documentation/tutorial too, and I haven't fount a lot of stuff to be clear, but I found a wiki that might be useful. Here it is if you want to check it out:

Mcjty's wiki: https://wiki.mcjty.eu/modding/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Forge's official documentation can be found here, versions:

- [1.15.x](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.x/)
- [1.16.x](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.16.x/)
- [1.17.x](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/1.17.x/)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't being clear. The official documentation is not complete as far as I can tell. It doesn't say which classes are in which packages, and is missing some other things.
example: It gives an explanation of how to adjust item properties, using an `Item$Properties` object, but doesn't explain how to access that object in the constructor of the Item class(this seems to be the only time in the code you can modify the properties) or how to put that object into the constructor.